# Change fields names in React

Tags: reactjs, api

I currently have this code, and in a spam it calls {image.processamento.result}

```
 renderImgs() {
const { images, loadingFetchImages } = this.state;
if (loadingFetchImages) {
  return <Loading />;
}
return images.map(image => (
    <div key={image.processamento.id} className="col-2">
      <div role="button" tabIndex={0} onKeyPress={() => this.checkImage(image.processamento.id)} onClick={() => this.checkImage(image.processamento.id)} className={`lista-img-validar ${image.check ? 'active' : ''}`}>
        <figure>
          <img src={image.public_url} id="image-authorize" className="img-responsive" alt="Imagem da prova" />
        </figure>
        <figcaption>
            <div className="col-12">
              <article className="text-left">
                <span className="validador-txt-destaque">{image.processamento.co_inscricao}</span>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12">
              <article className="text-left mt-2">
                <span className="validador-txt-destaque-silver">Lote: </span>
                <span>{image.processamento.batch}</span>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12">
              <article className="text-left mt-2">
                <span className="validador-txt-destaque-silver">Situação: </span>
                <span>{image.processamento.result}</span>
              </article>
            </div>                
        </figcaption>
      </div>
    </div>
));
}
```

{image.processamento.result} can return 3 values, "essay", "inssuficient" and "blank", all that I want to do is change this names when I'm rendering the images to the user, for ex. I want that "blank" becomes "Sem texto."

I'm confused because inside a return I can't use conditionals like if else etc, can someone help me?

Comment: Have you checked out ternary operators?? you could use it in your return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
renderImgs() {
const { images, loadingFetchImages } = this.state;
if (loadingFetchImages) {
  return <Loading />;
}

const getFriendlyName = function(name) {
    if(name == "blank"){
      return "Sem texto
    }
    return name
}

return images.map(image => (
    <div key={image.processamento.id} className="col-2">
      <div role="button" tabIndex={0} onKeyPress={() => this.checkImage(image.processamento.id)} onClick={() => this.checkImage(image.processamento.id)} className={`lista-img-validar ${image.check ? 'active' : ''}`}>
        <figure>
          <img src={image.public_url} id="image-authorize" className="img-responsive" alt="Imagem da prova" />
        </figure>
        <figcaption>
            <div className="col-12">
              <article className="text-left">
                <span className="validador-txt-destaque">{image.processamento.co_inscricao}</span>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12">
              <article className="text-left mt-2">
                <span className="validador-txt-destaque-silver">Lote: </span>
                <span>{image.processamento.batch}</span>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12">
              <article className="text-left mt-2">
                <span className="validador-txt-destaque-silver">Situação: </span>
                <span>{getFriendlyName(image.processamento.result)}</span>
              </article>
            </div>                
        </figcaption>
      </div>
    </div>
));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
<span>{image.processamento.result == "blank" ? "Sem texto" : image.processamento.result }</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this from many ways, I think the right way you can do this:

```
const status = [
   blank:"some blank text",
   essay:"some essay text",
   inssuficient:"some inssuficient text"
];
<span>{status[image.processamento.result]}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operators are essential in JSX. They can also be chained, much like if/elses,

This would be valid:

`<span>{image.processamento.result === 'blank' ? "Sem texto" : image.processamento.result === 'insufficient' ? 'Não suficiente' : image.processamento.result }</span>`

Of course, this can all be abstracted before returning the jsx tag into if statements. Inside your `map`, instead of a shorthand return, you would just do an explicit return, and declare a variable representing the result before that. But that's really just a matter of preference.